# Auto-upload image to PC when taking screenshot from TV using AVerMedia card

Tags: media

I have an AVerMedia card connecting the TV to laptop by PCI and USB. I want every time I save a screenshot from TV, the image will be auto-sent to PC.

The problem is, I have no clue where to start. I read all posts related to AVerMedia card like [this in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284008/how-can-i-grab-video-from-usb-video-capture-dvb-device-with-gstreamer) or [this in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446975/programmatically-add-avi-file-header-to-video-stream) or [this in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432345/opencv-cvcapturefromcamcv-cap-dshow-capture-blank-frame), but still no clue where to start.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is this related to [tag:android] at all?

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? The way you phrased your original question makes it sound as though you may not, in which case you'll need to learn that first.

Comment: @duskwuff: i know php, ios and c#(just the basic) and in this case i'm not sure i can use them( c# may be). The good answer for me i think is the name of the language i can use or any book i can put myself into, you know basic step by step for a starter. I got time to read and try. Tks for your comment by the way :D